# Flutter initState called more than once

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget with `initState` implemented. There is no navigation in the app yet, just one screen. Everything works fine unless the back button is pressed. Then the app is sent to background. On bringing the app back in foreground `initState` is called again (which to my understanding should not be happening).

The app uses `Amplify` and in `initState` `Amplify` is configured. On app launch configuration works well. But in this case (back button + coming back from background) the app attempts to configure `Amplify` again because `initState` is called again and I get: `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configure on channel com.amazonaws.amplify/core)`.

Not sure what is causing the issue, but the guess is that it is because `initState` should not be called again - any ideas why this is happening? Thank you in advance.

Parts of the code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
        currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
      currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppGray,
      appBar: null,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(//...etc.
```

Here is the configure method:

```
Future<bool> _configureAmplify() async {
    final Amplify amplifyInstance = Amplify();
    final AmplifyAuthCognito auth = AmplifyAuthCognito();

    setState(() {
      _amplifyConfigured = false;
    });

    // Add Cognito Plugins
    try {
      await amplifyInstance.addPlugin(authPlugins: [auth]);
    } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    setState(() {
      isAmplifyConfigureError = true;
    });
  }

  // Once Plugins are added, configure Amplify
  try {
    await amplifyInstance
        .configure(amplifyconfig); //<- here the error happens
    setState(() {
      _amplifyConfigured = true;
    });
    attemptToFetchSession(context);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    setState(() {
      isAmplifyConfigureError = true;
    });
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this question can be improved by focusing on one particular problem. Maybe eliminating unrelated code.

Comment: @Alex.F Thank you for your feedback. The issue originally was that initState is called after user resumes foreground after going to background with the back button. But I was asked for more code so I added it to the question thinking it will provide more information - do you have any advice how to do this without making the question more unclear?

Comment: check my update response. The first line of `_configureAmplify` should be `if (!mounted) return;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is the main screen should not be rebuilt at all, so you shouldn't respond to back button at all in this screen, because it is disposing of your state and then it has to re-initialize it. Generally you shouldn't let the user press back while in the root screen, Try wrapping your main screen in a willPopScope.

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => false, child : ....
```

But normally if you set initial route this shouldn't happen in the first place to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! I will use it as a workaround for now. It's weird that the activity is destroyed on pressing the back button and weirder that the amplify configuration stops working after that. There are some workaround to this as described here - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/99 - but this is probably the fastest workaround, so I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks! The thing is if you set up your routing system and add an initial route, the navigator won't try to pop your main screen anymore so you wouldn't have this problem because it identifies the initial route as root. Also try to clear your main material app of anything and add everything as the home as a separate widget so that nothing will unnecessarily initiate rebuild of your main material app. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

InitState is called each time before the StateFullWidget build. So when the app is sent to the background, the stateful widget disposes and rebuild with the app is opened.

You should move the `_configureAmplify()` to the main class before runApp() is called.

Do the following.

```
Future<void> main() async {
   /** WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() is required in Flutter v1.9.4+ before using any plugins if the code is executed before runApp. */
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

_configureAmplify();

runApp(MapApp());

}
```

**UPDATE**

You should always check if your widget is mounted or not before trying to configure.

```
_configureAmplify() {
 if (!mounted) return;

 ... // The rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your solution and it turns out even main is called again on coming from background. So I guess the app is restarted or something, but not completely, since the configuration fails this time and on start succeeds? I am very new to flutter, do you have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Can I see the contents of _configureAmplify()?

Comment: I updated the question with the contents of _configureAmplify()

Comment: You are right I should check if it is mounted, however even so the issue remains. I found this issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/99 where it's stated that "the back button causes the FlutterActivity to be destroyed in Android instead of sending it to background". It's weird, but apparently this is the reason for calling main and initState again, which leads to unsuccessful configuration for some reason. Thank you for your help!